# Nuxt.js not passing body params when using this.$http.post

Tags: javascript, express, nuxt.js

I'm having this issue where when i use the this.$http.post and this.$http.patch method that @nuxt/http provides causes issues with parsing body parameters when posting. The weird thing is that it used to work, so i wouldn't even know where to start.

Could anyone guide me to where I could start looking for the solution?

Thanks

Here is my client code

`await this.$http.patch("http://localhost:3000/api/tasks/${task.id}",{task:"rando info here"})`

and in my app.js express server it looks like this

```
    app.use(express.json({strict:false}));
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
    app.use('/tasks', taskRouter)
```

and in my routes/tasks.js

```
    router.patch('/:taskId', function(req,res,next){
        console.log(req.body)
        #a bunch of sql related code
    })
```

just so I can see what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't worry.. I figured it out. It had to do with the fact I was using the @nuxt/http module. For some reason this.$http.post('apilink:3000', {body: bodyinfo}) doesn't send body. It must be a bug.

What worked for me was changing to axios.

```
this.$axios.post('apilink:3000', {body:bodyinfo})
```

for whatever reason that passes the body instead of the other one.